# Not able to create a table with JSON datatype in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table in Bigquery with Json data type and getting below error

```
CREATE TABLE mydataset.table1(
  id INT64,
  cart JSON
);
```

Error :

```
Error running query
Type not found: JSON at [4:8]
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data

Is this Supported in Bigquery ?

Answer (score 1):

The `JSON` is unfortunately not Generally Available yet

> This product or feature is covered by the Pre-GA Offerings Terms of the Google Cloud Terms of Service. Pre-GA products and features might have limited support, and changes to pre-GA products and features might not be compatible with other pre-GA versions. For more information, see the launch stage descriptions.

But apparently in order to test it you can try to apply:

> To enroll in this preview, complete the [enrollment form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1wfA1FVxIi8nV73vF4wgBrHm09Ue-FMwdBR_Ix19SXvA/viewform).